# Is it possible to have a WCF 3.5 client with WCF 4.0 server and NetTCPBinding?

Tags: wcf, wcf-security, wcf-client

I had a .Net 4 WCF Windows Service, using NetTCPBinding in anonymous mode (security = none) which worked fine.
However after a requirement change the client needs to be .Net 3.5.
I tried changing only the client to .Net 3.5 but it complained that the request could not be upgraded; I think .Net 3.5 does not support anonymous NetTCP.
Is there a way to do this: .Net 3.5 client -> .Net 4.0 service with NetTCP anonynous ?
Note I tried to changing the service to .Net 3.5 as well but that requires to set up at least transport level security. The service will run on a trusted local area network and I'd prefer an anonymous client/service.

Comment: The netTcpBinding documentation for the [security element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731316(v=vs.90).aspx) in all versions (3.0, 3.5 & 4.0) supports setting the mode attribute to "none". I don't believe the issue is due to the security mode setting, could you put the specific exception message & stack trace in the question.

Comment: I've found out that the issue appears only when I use the service from a DLL which has the service reference. If I use the service reference directly it works. I'll post the exception/stack trace.